# Custom ViewFlipper not working?

Tags: java, android

Here is a simplified code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class main extends Activity {

    public myFlipper flipper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        flipper = (myFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    }

    class myFlipper extends ViewFlipper
    {

        public myFlipper(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }

}
```

Java throws a classCastException when I try to do this, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out to those of you who are interested.

You need to add a constructor that allows for Layout attributes in your custom view class. Like so:

```
    public myFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

And you need to follow Cristian´s example as well. Then it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your custom view on the XML too:

```
<view class="your.package.main$myFlipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    etc.
/>
```

Extra advice: classes should be declared with the first letter in upper case.

Comment: My XML now looks like this: <com.test.main$myFlipper 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1" /> , Eclipse says there was an error in my XML and disallows building.

Comment: Now It throws an InflateException :/ I think it's because I need to write some custom Inflation behaviour to handle the attributes (layout_width etc.)